# JAVA program accepting Devanagari(UTF8) charaters

Tags: java, php, eclipse, utf-8

What settings are needed so that Java class main method can accept Marathi/Devanagarai/UTF-8 characters. 
e.g.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(args[0]);
       System.out.println("भारत");
    }
```

In eclipse Java run arguments if I specify argument as "abc" it prints

```
abc
भारत
```

But If I specify Marathi/Devanagarai/UTF-8 string e.g. "कौशिक" then it prints

```
?????
भारत
```

What extra settings to be done in eclipse ? 
Later I want to excute this program from jar using command and call it from PHP
e.g.
    java -cp xyz.jar DevanagariTest कौशिक 
What extra parameters will be needed at that time ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This works fine for me on Eclipse Oxygen. Exactly how are you specifying the arguments? What do you have for the Encoding on the Common tab of the Run Configuration?

Comment: I added image of my configuration. Please check.

Comment: You still haven't shown us the Encoding setting on the Common tab.

Comment: added another screenshot. Plz check now

Comment: As workaround you could encode/decode the argument, e. g. `%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8C%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%95` instead of `कौशिक` and `java.net.URLDecoder.decode(args[0], "UTF-8")` instead of `args[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with your default system encoding. You can try to start the Java Programm with an additional Argument:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: It did not work. I added image of my configuration. Please check.